# Seemingly unnecessary bitcast -> phi -> bitcast being generated

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am having a problem where Clang is seemingly generating unnecessary bitcasts (from f32 -> i32 -> f32. The following piece is the generated IR (with stripped out irrelevant pieces. I tried highlighting the relevant lines but that does not work in a code block.

The problem is the bitcast defining %5, followed by the duplicated phi nodes (%6 and %7), and a bitcast store which is the last line. I don't see a reason why this datapath is bitcasted into i32, it is not being used anywhere else.

The corresponding c code contains only float data types, some structs with nested arrays as data types, if elseif else constructs with some floating point constants (it is generated code). No clue as on why.

(ccode: https://pastebin.com/c0gYkwhF, llvm ir:  https://pastebin.com/NSyhSkUa)

tldr;

- Why is the bitcast to i32 being generated
- Can I prevent this somehow (don't want to deal with i32 datatype)

```
; Function Attrs: nofree norecurse nounwind uwtable
define dso_local void @CurrentControl_step() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
; (...)
  %mul3 = fmul fast float %4, 0x3FEFFFEF80000000
  %add4 = fadd fast float %3, %mul3
  %cmp = fcmp fast ogt float %add4, 0x3FEF400000000000
  br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else

; (...)

if.else7:                                         ; preds = %if.else
  store float %add4, float* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.DW_CurrentControl_T, %struct.DW_CurrentControl_T* @CurrentControl_DW, i64 0, i32 1, i64 0), align 4, !tbaa !2
  %5 = bitcast float %add4 to i32
  br label %if.end8

if.end8:                                          ; preds = %if.then6, %if.else7, %if.then
  %6 = phi i32 [ -1082523648, %if.then6 ], [ %5, %if.else7 ], [ 1064960000, %if.then ]
  %7 = phi float [ 0xBFEF400000000000, %if.then6 ], [ %add4, %if.else7 ], [ 0x3FEF400000000000, %if.then ]
; (...)
  %9 = fsub fast float %7, %mul9
; (...)
  store i32 %6, i32* bitcast (float* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.DW_CurrentControl_T, %struct.DW_CurrentControl_T* @CurrentControl_DW, i64 0, i32 2, i64 0) to i32*), align 4, !tbaa !2
; (...)
```

**EDIT:**
I have a new minimal example generating a seemingly unnecessary bitcast:

```
typedef struct {
    float nestedArray[2];
} Foo;

Foo s;
float testVar;

void test(void) {
    testVar = s.nestedArray[0];
}
```

which generates:

```
%struct.Foo = type { [2 x float] }

@s = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global %struct.Foo zeroinitializer, align 4
@var = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global float 0.000000e+00, align 4

; Function Attrs: nofree norecurse nounwind uwtable
define dso_local void @test() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load i32, i32* bitcast (%struct.Foo* @s to i32*), align 4, !tbaa !2
  store i32 %0, i32* bitcast (float* @var to i32*), align 4, !tbaa !2
  ret void
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; the struct type used isn't shown. But that probably does not matter, because there's a simple way to find out what clang does: Set a breakpoint in CastInst::Create(), make it conditional on op, and compile (a reduced version of) your source code. The stack trace has your answer.

Comment: @arnt I have added a minimal example on the bottom of my post. I also tried attaching to clang but did not manage to do so. However with -print-after-all I managed to figure out it actually is the InstCombine pass which adds the bitcast. I tried reproducing by running opt -instcombine on the file but that did not insert te additional bitcast. EDIT: -O0 adds optnone flags everywhere, without those instcombine idd adds additional bitcasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcast was caused by: [doc](https://llvm.org/doxygen/InstCombineLoadStoreAlloca_8cpp_source.html#l00574)

```
// Try to canonicalize loads which are only ever stored to operate over
// integers instead of any other type. We only do this when the loaded type
// is sized and has a size exactly the same as its store size and the store
// size is a legal integer type.
// Do not perform canonicalization if minmax pattern is found (to avoid
// infinite loop).
```